# Iterating through ports to determine which devices are connected with PySerial

Tags: python, json, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to create a function using pySerial (on Linux Mint) that will iterate through all serial ports and determine which devices are connected to which ports. Each device has a "configuration file" that has a json format and contains the serial parameters such as bytesize, stopbits, baudrate, its *IDN? equivalent and the expected response. Here is part of the json file that is loaded as hwparams:

```
{
    "nanovoltmeter": {
      "baudrate": 19200,
      "bytesize": 8,
      "ending": "\n",
      "fresh_pattern": "[-+]?[0-9]\\.[0-9]*E[-+]?[0-9]*",
      "greeting": "*IDN?",
      "name": "nanovoltmeter",
      "parity": "N",
      "port": "/dev/ttyS6",
      "response": "MODEL 2182A",
      "stopbits": 1,
      "timeout": 1,
      "xonxoff": false
    },
    "pressure_monitor": {
      "RD_pattern": "\\*   [+\\-]?[^A-Za-z]?(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d+)",
      "baudrate": 57600,
      "bytesize": 8,
      "ending": "\r",
      "greeting": "#hello",
      "ig3s_pattern": "\\*   [0,1] IG (ON|OFF)",
      "name": "pressure monitor",
      "parity": "N",
      "port": "/dev/ttyS4",
      "response": " ?   SYNTX ER",
      "stopbits": 1,
      "timeout": 1,
      "xonxoff": false
    },
    "temperature_controller": {
      "aout_pattern": "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]",
      "baudrate": 57600,
      "bytesize": 7,
      "ending": "\r\n",
      "greeting": "*IDN?",
      "krdg0_pattern": "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*,[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*,[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*,[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*",
      "krdga_pattern": "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*",
      "name": "temperature controller",
      "parity": "O",
      "port": "/dev/ttyUSB1",
      "response": "LSCI,MODEL336",
      "setp_pattern": "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*",
      "stopbits": 1,
      "timeout": 1,
      "xonxoff": false
    }
  }
}
```

In the example below I iterate over the list of devices in the order that matches the order in which the ports are explored. For example, I know that the pressure_monitor device is attached to /dev/tty7 -- which is the first port in the list returned by comports() -- and so it is first on the list. If I do not provide the devices in the right order, some of the devices will never be found. For example, if the list of devices has the nanovoltmeter after the temperature_controller, none of them gets detected, e.g., at the time when the port of the nanovoltmeter is tested, the pressure_monitor has already been detected and the first attempt to open a serial connection uses the parameters of the temperature_controller. Querying returns None, the connection is closed and the buffers are reset, a new Serial object is created with the parameters of the Nanovoltmeter is created and the query also returns None. If the order is inverted, the code works as it should.

As it stands, my code is not very helpful because it requires prior knowledge of the connections, but I don't understand why it fails. It's almost as if ser.close() or ser.reset_input_buffer() were not doing what I think they should do, or not releasing the port.

from serial.tools.list_ports import comports
import re, serial
import numpy as np
import json

```
def configure_ports(config_directory='config'):
    
    hwparams = load_json(fname='hwparams.json', location=config_directory)
    devices = hwparams["devices"]

    configuration = {}
    for device in list(devices.keys()):
        configuration[device] = None

    for comport in comports():
        port = comport[0]
        
        for device in ['pressure_monitor', 'nanovoltmeter', 'current_source_tc', 'temperature_controller']:

            if configuration[device] is None:
            
                it_worked = configure_device(devices[device], port, vb=True)
                if it_worked:
                    configuration[device] = port
                    break
    time.sleep(.2)


def configure_device(device, usb_port='/dev/ttyUSB0', vb=False):
    ser, success = None, False
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(usb_port, baudrate=device['baudrate'], bytesize=device['bytesize'], stopbits=device['stopbits'], parity=device['parity'], xonxoff=device['xonxoff'], timeout=device['timeout'])
        ser.reset_input_buffer()
        ser.reset_output_buffer()
        ser.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ser.write(bytes(device['greeting']+device['ending'],'utf-8'))

        r = ser.readline().decode('utf-8', errors='backslashreplace').strip()

        if re.search(device['response'], r):
            success = True

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        
    finally:
        if ser is not None:
            ser.reset_input_buffer()
            ser.reset_output_buffer()
            ser.close()
            ser.__del__()
            
    return success
```